# Unable to configure SqlDataProvider in Audit.Net when MVC multiple layered application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, audit.net, audit.net.sqlserver

I have web project using ASP.Net MVC. And, project structure is

1. Libraries

   - Core
   - Data (I have used `AuditScope` to capture audit events to store them in sql that configured in web)
   - Services
2. Presentation

   - Web (I have a configuration class to use `SqlDataProvider` for Audit.Net)
   - Web Framework

The above settings not working as in the Data project `AuditScope` didn't recognize `SqlDataProvider`. I believe it happened because Data layer project didn't aware of the registration in Web project. If so, how to configure this?

Here below, I have attached code to configure and capture audit event what i used.

**Configuration Class:**

```
public static class AuditNetRegistrar
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        Configuration.Setup()
            .UseSqlServer(config => config
                            .ConnectionString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["masterConnection"].ToString())
                            .Schema("Audit")
                            .IdColumnName("EventId")
                            .JsonColumnName("JsonData")
                            .LastUpdatedColumnName("LastUpdatedDate")
                            .CustomColumn("EventType", ev => ev.EventType)
                            .CustomColumn("User", ev => ev.Environment.UserName)
                            .TableName("General"));
    }
}
```

**Startup Class: (Web)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        AuditNetRegistrar.Register();
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

**Repository Class: (Data)**

```
public void InsertUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
{
    using (var audit = AuditScope.Create("UserProfile:Insert", () => userProfile))
    {
        _dbContext.Insert(userProfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? is the audit event saved on a .json file on disk (default behavior)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but also need this nugget package to write to SQL from Audit.net

https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.SqlServer/README.md